# A bit of math programming. 4 colors on a grid

Tags: math

Let's say I have a grid

```
-----
| | |
-----
| | |
-----
```

And I have 4 colors, Red, Blue, Green, and Yellow. I am trying to figure out how many different combinations there can be using those colors in the each way. For instance I might have:

```
BR      BR      BY      BY    
GY      YG      RG      GR
```

etc. 
I can use the same color more than once so it can be like this:

```
BB             BB         BB
RR    or even  BR    or   BB
```

I tried drawing out the different combos but I always end up getting more confused the more I draw them out. I'm trying to figure this out because I'm  using it for a tile system for a game I'm trying to plan out. I just need to know the different combos so I'd know how many tiles I'd need to cover everything.

There has to be a math way to solve this, I just can't figure it out for the life of me.

Thanks in advance oh math programming gods. I'll be forever in your debt

Comment: 4 locations, 4 colours, so total possibilities = 4^4 = 256.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Saying math has nothing to do with programming is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you described, this seems to be a simple problem of combinatronics.

For each grid, there are four colors possible. And there are four grids.
so answer should be 4*4*4*4 = 4^4 = 256 possible ways.

Comment: Is that taking into account that there can be the same color multiple times per grid of 4? I thought I could only do that if there was exactly 1 color per grid

Comment: That is exactly *because* there can be repeated colours. If you had to have unique colours then it would be 4*3*2*1 (four choices for the first cell, then three remaining possiblities for the second, etc.).

Comment: Yes, this accounts for that case. The idea is that each cell's color is independent of the others, and when you have independent choices for a group of objects you multiply together the number of options for each object.

Comment: @robamcclellan yes it is taking into account that same color can be used multiple times. As Chris mentioned, if repeated colors are not allowed, then the answer would be 4*3*2*1.